# Upgrade of Java 8 and MQ - NoClassDEfFoundError

Tags: java, ibm-mq

we recently upgraded our code to Java 8. As part of it MQ was also upgraded to MQ 9. We are using two components jms(7.0.1.6) and jmqi(7.0.1.6) earlier.
    Now we replaced both the jars with allclient and tracecontrol of MQ 9.0.0.0 JAR.

```
2017-10-24 02:30:07 INFO  server.SqlService<start:29> -  SQL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSRuntimeException
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination.<clinit>(MQDestination.java:71)
    at com.epo.core.server.config.LdapConfig.getQueue(LdapConfig.java:213)
    at com.epo.core.server.MqService.start(MqService.java:77)
    at com.epo.core.service.ServiceGroup.start(ServiceGroup.java:90)
    at com.epo.core.service.ServiceGroup.startAll(ServiceGroup.java:76)
    at com.epo.core.service.ServiceGroup.start(ServiceGroup.java:70)
    at com.epo.server.dispatcher.DispatcherProcess.initializeServices(DispatcherProcess.java:380)
    at com.epo.server.dispatcher.DispatcherProcess.run(DispatcherProcess.java:320)
    at com.epo.server.dispatcher.DispatcherProcess.main(DispatcherProcess.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findCl`enter code here`ass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Please let me know why I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Note that for questions related to the IBM MQ product you should use the [ibm-mq] tag not the [mq] tag, I have edited your question and replaced [mq] with [ibm-mq]

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
```

because you don't have the JMS v2.0 jar on your classpath.  You're probably still using the JMS v1.1 jar.

Look at how your application configures its Java classpath to correct the issue.

Note that if you didn't copy the MQ client libraries around, and just referenced the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar file on the Java classapth from a real MQ client install, you wouldn't have this problem as the JMS v2.0 jar will exist alongside the allclient jar in the MQ_INSTALLATION_DIR/java/lib directory and would be pulled into auto-magically.

Comment: @a _conish_pasty  Thanks for the reply. I have added the javax.jms-api 2.0.1 version. But now classnotfounderror is not coming.

Comment: Right now I am getting the following error com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException=com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager '****' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'W-******'.

Comment: @SindhuriDevatha the new error is a different unrelated problem and should be asked as a new question.  If you feel that either answer helped you solve the `NoClassDefFoundError` found error you were receiving them please accept one of them.  I would then suggest searching on StackOverflow for the new error as I'm sure there are a few different questions that address this.  If you can't find one then post a new question related to your new error.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by a_cornish_pasty you are likely missing the jms.jar or have an older version.

For **IBM MQ Classes for JMS** you can find the list of files required on the IBM MQ v9 Knowledge Center page "[What is installed for IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031540_.htm)":

> **Relocatable JAR files**
>   Within an enterprise, the following files can be moved to systems that need to run IBM MQ classes for JMS:
>
> - com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
> - com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
> - jms.jar
> - fscontext.jar
> - providerutil.jar
> - The Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jars
>
> The fscontext.jar and providerutil.jar files are required if your application performs JNDI lookups using a file system context.
>
> The Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jar files are required. For more information, see Support for non-IBM JREs.

Note that only `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`, `jms.jar`, and the Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jars are included in the Redistributable client, but all are included in Java All client.  You are also running 9.0.0.0 and I would recommend you go to 9.0.0.2.  You can find both the Redistributable and Java All clients on [Fix Central](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=9.0&platform=All&function=textSearch&text=Java).