# jmeter (jms point-to-point) error while connecting IBM - MQ : javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq, jndi

jmeter (jms point-to-point) error while connecting IBM - MQ :

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
```

Need help in resolving the error. FYI: `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` is added in lib folder, 32 bit jdk 1.8

[jms point-to-point configuration in jemeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsa4l.png)

[JNDI configuration in mq explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4REBx.png)

After adding the jars (copied all the MQ Jars (that comes with a complete Websphere MQ installation) and placing them into JMeter/Lib) new error encountered:

```
Error: Response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
```

Binding file is there in place (C:\Users*****\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\JNDI-Directory)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: JoshMc - I have updated the question.

Comment: Note once you get to 15 reputation you have the ability to upvote answers to any question including your own.  If the answers I linked to by @AttilaRepasi also helped  you then it would be a nice gesture to go and upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not state which version of IBM MQ jar files you are using, however com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar was introduced in IBM MQ v8, so you must be using v8 or v9.

---

The v9 Knowledge Center page "[What is installed for IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031540_.htm)" states the following:

> The fscontext.jar and providerutil.jar files are required if your application performs JNDI lookups using a file system context.

---

In summary you need to include the following jar files:

- `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`
- `jms.jar`
- `fscontext.jar`
- `providerutil.jar`

See my answer to "[Upgrade of Java 8 and MQ - NoClassDEfFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931561/upgrade-of-java-8-and-mq-noclassdeffounderror/46940454#46940454) for more information.

---

**UPDATE 2018-01-25**

Related to the secondary error:

```
Error: Response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
```

In the following answer Attila Repasi addresses the error you are receiving:

[JMeter 3.2 Point-to-Point configuration for IBM MQ 8 => Java Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340608/jmeter-3-2-point-to-point-configuration-for-ibm-mq-8-java-exception/46357907#46357907)

The answer states:

> Create a MQQueueConnectionFactory in MQExplorer instead of the
>   MQConnectionFactory you have now.

In addition in the following answer Attila Repasi describes how to configure JMeter with IBM MQ v8 and addresses what to do in MQ Explorer.

[JMeter configuration for IBM MQ 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200688/jmeter-configuration-for-ibm-mq-8/46238776#46238776)

Comment: Thanks for the information, error resolved after adding these jars. However another error encountered: Response message: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: C:\Users\*****\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\JNDI-Directory\ [Root exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c]

Answer (score 0):

According to [oracle post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1158121?start=0) you are missing fscontext.jar

> the ClassNotFoundException for com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory is solved by adding fscontext.jar to your classpath

You can download it [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/com/sun/jndi/fscontext/RefFSContextFactory.html) and copy it  to JMeter lib folder

Comment: Thanks for the information, error resolved after adding these jars. However another error encountered: Response message: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: C:\Users*****\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\‌​JNDI-Directory\ [Root exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c]

Answer (score 0):

You need to either drop required libraries somewhere under [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) or set *user.classpath* property to point to the folder where they live.

According to Getting the [IBM MQ classes for Java and JMS](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398):

> .\JavaSE:
>
> com.ibm.mq.
>
> allclient.jar
>
> com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
>
> fscontext.jar
>
> jms.jar
>
> providerutil.jar
>
> JSON4J.jar

So you need not only `allclient.jar`, you need **all the jars** from the `JavaSE` folder.

More information: [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)